# Recyclerview List in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-listadapter

I want to display my recyclerview list in a fragment. There are no data shows when I run the app. 
Here's my Moviesfragment:

```
    public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {
        private RecyclerView rvMovies;
        private ArrayList<Movies> list = new ArrayList<>();
        public MoviesFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
            rvMovies = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_movies);
            rvMovies.setHasFixedSize(true);

            list.addAll(getListMovie());
            showRecyclerList();

            return view;
        }

        public ArrayList<Movies> getListMovie(){
            String [] dataTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MovieTitle);
            String [] dataReleases = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MovieReleaseInfo);
            String [] dataDirectors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MovieDirectors);
            String [] dataGenres = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MovieGenres);
            String [] dataPhoto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MovieImage);

            ArrayList<Movies> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < dataTitles.length; i++){
                Movies movies = new Movies();
                movies.setPhoto(dataPhoto[i]);
                movies.setTitle(dataTitles[i]);
                movies.setRelease_info(dataReleases[i]);
                movies.setDirector(dataDirectors[i]);
                movies.setGenres(dataGenres[i]);

                listMovie.add(movies);
            }
            return listMovie;
        }

        private void showRecyclerList(){
            rvMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
            ListMoviesAdapter listMoviesAdapter = new ListMoviesAdapter(list);
            rvMovies.setAdapter(listMoviesAdapter);

        }

    }
```

Here is my adapter:

```
  public class ListMoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListMoviesAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
      private ArrayList<Movies> listMovies;

      public ListMoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Movies> list){
          this.listMovies = list;
      }

      public void setListMovies(ArrayList<Movies> list){
          this.listMovies = list;
      }
      @NonNull
      @Override
      public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_movies, parent, false);
          return new ListViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
          Movies movies = listMovies.get(position);
          Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                  .load(movies.getPhoto())
                  .apply(new RequestOptions().override(55,55))
                  .into(holder.imgPhoto);

                  holder.tvTitle.setText(movies.getTitle());
                  holder.tvRelease.setText(movies.getRelease_info());
                  holder.tvDirector.setText(movies.getDirector());
                  holder.tvGenre.setText(movies.getGenres());
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return 0;
      }

      public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          ImageView imgPhoto;
          TextView tvTitle, tvRelease, tvDirector, tvGenre;

          public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
              super(itemView);
              imgPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_movies);
              tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_movies_name);
              tvRelease = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_movies_release);
              tvDirector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_movies_directors);
              tvGenre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_movies_genres);
          }
      }

  }
```

Movie.java:

```
     private String title;
     private String release_info;
     private String genres;
     private String director;
     private String photo;

     public String getTitle() {
         return title;
     }

     public void setTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title;
     }

     public String getRelease_info() {
         return release_info;
     }

     public void setRelease_info(String release_info) {
         this.release_info = release_info;
     }

     public String getGenres() {
         return genres;
     }

     public void setGenres(String genres) {
         this.genres = genres;
     }

     public String getDirector() {
         return director;
     }

     public void setDirector(String director) {
         this.director = director;
     }

     public String getPhoto() {
         return photo;
     }

     public void setPhoto(String photo) {
         this.photo = photo;
     }

     @Override
     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
         dest.writeString(this.title);
         dest.writeString(this.release_info);
         dest.writeString(this.director);
         dest.writeString(this.genres);
         dest.writeString(this.photo);
     }

     Movies(){}

     private Movies(Parcel in){
         this.title = in.readString();
         this.release_info = in.readString();
         this.director = in.readString();
         this.genres = in.readString();
         this.photo = in.readString();
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movies>(){
         @Override
         public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel source){
             return new Movies(source);
         }

         @Override
         public Movies[] newArray(int size){
             return new Movies[size];
         }
     };
 }
```

Here's my item_row_movies:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_movies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_movies"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_movies"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_movies_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_movies_release"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textSize="8sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_movies_directors"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textSize="8sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_movies_genres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textSize="8sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my fragment movies layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MoviesFragment">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Movies_Tab_title" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_movies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_row_movies"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

I already tried to change from this() in layoutmanager to this.getContext() since it's not an activity. There is no error shown, but the list didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

set layout manager for list after setting adapter

```
rvMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: can not be applied

Comment: @Leony set laymanger need context of activity, so instead of pass ```this``` pass ```getContext()```

Comment: get context from "container"

Answer (score 0):

After set adapter its need to notify adapter to get the result in recycler view.

```
    private void showRecyclerList(){
        rvMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        ListMoviesAdapter listMoviesAdapter = new ListMoviesAdapter(list);
        rvMovies.setAdapter(listMoviesAdapter);
        // here is the changes
        listMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And in your adapter inside get =ItemCount method need to return size of your movie list.

```
  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      //i.e
      return listMovies != null ? listMovies.size() : 0;
  }
```

happy coding :)

Refer this thread to understand recycler view custom adapter
https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/web-service-backends-and-custom-fragments/custom-adapters-with-recyclerview

Comment: still no result